# Selecting multiple rows from two tables in one go in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables:

```
products (id,title,price)
types (id,idProduct,type,additionalPrice).
```

I want to make a list that shows all the products and their subsequent types in the most efficient way possible, basically something like this:

```
Product1 (price1)
ProductType1 (+x USD)
ProductType2 (+y USD)

Product2 (price2)
ProductType3 (+w USD)
ProductType4 (+z USD)

etc
```

One solution I can think of is using GROUP_CONCAT and exploding the results in PHP, but something tells me there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest querying a record set of the following values...

- `Products.ID`
- `Products.Title`
- `Products.Price`
- `Types.Type`
- `Types.AdditionalPrice`

... and then just use PHP to handle the formatting once you have the data. If you order the results by `Products.Title` and `Types.Type` it should be pretty easy to get the output you want with minimal PHP coding.

The query would looks like this:

```
SELECT
  Products.ID
  Products.Title
  Products.Price
  Types.Type
  Types.AdditionalPrice
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Types ON Products.ID = Types.idProducts
ORDER BY Products.Title, Types.Type
```

You may not even need the `Products.ID` value, though it's often useful to have a PK available at the front end. At any rate, you can omit it from the `SELECT` list (but not the join!) and the query will be fine.

Comment: I implemented this solution, it's the most straightforward. I was hoping for something more esoteric :) Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked out! I like the more involved solutions too - maybe next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is what you are looking for pandronic:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.price, t.type
FROM products p
INNER JOIN types t ON (t.idProduct = p.id)
```

if you want to group your result set by products,  then you can do it

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.price, GROUP_CONCAT(t.type)
FROM products p
INNER JOIN types t ON (t.idProduct = p.id)
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Nope, I knew about GROUP_CONCAT, but it felt kinda hacky.